# Auto Increment Zend/Db/Sql/Ddl Database migration

Tags: php, zend-framework, migration, database-migration, ddl

I'm trying to make a migration in Zend Framework 2 using https://github.com/vgarvardt/ZfSimpleMigrations
The problem is that I can't use the option 'auto_increment' it simply doesn't do anything.
I tried it in many ways but it seems not working. Does anyone who has been using this know how to do it ?

```
code Example: 
$table = new CreateTable('my_table');
    $column = new Integer('id', false);
    $column->setOption('auto_increment', true);
    $table->addColumn($column);
    $table->addConstraint(new PrimaryKey('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The auto increment only works with MySQL driver at the moment. if you set your option to
'autoincrement', 'identity' or 'serial' it will add an auto increment option to the SQL statement. like

```
$table = new CreateTable('my_table');
$column = new Integer('id', false);
$column->setOption('autoincrement', true);
$table->addColumn($column);
$table->addConstraint(new PrimaryKey('id'));
```

If you are trying this with SQLite then it wont work yet.